# Corda RSA issue using createKeystoreForCordaNode

Tags: corda

I am getting the following exception when I use the Corda createKeystoreForCordaNode function.

I did create a JKS RSA 2048 root and intermediate CA Keystore by KeyStore Explorer 5.3.1 or keytool command.

I also set the DEFAULT_TLS_SIGNATURE_SCHEME to RSA_SHA256.

> Exception in thread "main" org.bouncycastle.cert.CertException: unable to process signature: exception on setup: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.1 Signature not available
>                  at org.bouncycastle.cert.X509CertificateHolder.isSignatureValid(Unknown Source)
>                  at net.corda.node.utilities.X509Utilities.createCertificate$node_main(X509Utilities.kt:281)
>                  at net.corda.node.utilities.X509Utilities.createCertificate(X509Utilities.kt:142)
>                  at net.corda.node.utilities.X509Utilities.createCertificate(X509Utilities.kt:118)
>                  at net.corda.node.utilities.X509Utilities.createCertificate$default(X509Utilities.kt:117)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Support for PKCS1 RSA signatures "1.2.840.113549.1.1.1" will be added in Corda V3.

Also note that current recommendation for key size (if you create keys using Corda's api) is 3072bit, but I think a 2048bit key will work as well.
Source code in master branch verifies Corda's upcoming support for RSA *"1.2.840.113549.1.1.1"*.

```
val RSA_SHA256 = SignatureScheme(
        1,
        "RSA_SHA256",
        AlgorithmIdentifier(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.sha256WithRSAEncryption, null),
        listOf(AlgorithmIdentifier(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.rsaEncryption, null)), // This is 1.2.840.113549.1.1.1
        BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME,
        "RSA",
        "SHA256WITHRSAEncryption",
        null,
        3072,
        "PKCS1 RSA signature scheme using SHA256 as hash algorithm."
)
```

Alternatively, instead of using RSA keys, you can generate ECDSA keys using the NIST P-256 (secp256r1 named curve).
With `keytool` this is:

```
-keyalg EC -keysize 256 -sigalg SHA256withECDSA
```