# Support for PKCS1 RSA added in Corda V3?

Tags: rsa, corda

I would like to check if in corda version 3 we have support for Support for PKCS1 RSA signatures "1.2.840.113549.1.1.1".
We reported an issue in below thread and looks like should be included in this version.

[Corda RSA issue using createKeystoreForCordaNode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47544738/corda-rsa-issue-using-createkeystoreforcordanode)

Thanks!!

Javier

Comment: Why would you ask that question here?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Corda release-V3](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/release-V3/core/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/core/crypto/Crypto.kt), there is indeed support for PKCS1 RSA, see below:

```
/**
 * RSA PKCS#1 signature scheme using SHA256 for message hashing.
 * The actual algorithm id is 1.2.840.113549.1.1.1
 * Note: Recommended key size >= 3072 bits.
 */
@JvmField
val RSA_SHA256 = SignatureScheme(
        1,
        "RSA_SHA256",
        AlgorithmIdentifier(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.sha256WithRSAEncryption, null),
        listOf(AlgorithmIdentifier(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.rsaEncryption, null)),
        BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME,
        "RSA",
        "SHA256WITHRSA",
        null,
        3072,
        "RSA_SHA256 signature scheme using SHA256 as hash algorithm."
)
```